# Create new column with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

How can I create a completely new column with the same value for each line in an SQL SELECT query.

I am trying to SELECT records from my database but I need to create a new column with generic content so for each item, the column will have the same value. We'll name the column **test** and the content **content**. Can anybody show me how to do this? I'm new at SQL queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT column_1,
       column_2,
       'content' as test
FROM your_table
```

Comment: @user1090389: that should work with any version of SQL Server (actualy with *every* SQL DBMS)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was missing a comma. I'll accept as soon as it lets me